# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the new RecyclerView but when I put it on my project it give me this error in JellyBean 4.1.2

```
E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker', referenced from method com.redtab.android.MyApplication.getTracker
```

and when I take out the RecyclerView it does work.

here is my gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'   /// if i take it off the tracker works
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project('libs:ViewPageIndicator')
}
```

And in my MyApplication I have this:

```
 public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t =analytics.newTracker("XX-XXXXX");
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

I have test it with 4.1.2 and it doesn't work & with 5.0.2 and it works.

Using Android Studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using proguard, then the most likely fix will be adding this to your proguard file

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
```

Comment: I added in the proguard file and it doesn't work the log said "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker" when I call the getTracker();

Comment: Hm. Are you sure it's in the correct proguard file/does your build.gradle reference the proguard file that you edited??

Comment: actually I have this   debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }    so I have not enable the proguard